# How to translate words from $this->Time->timeAgoInWords?

Tags: cakephp-3.0

Here some translations at `default.po`

```
/src/Locale/pt_BR/default.po

msgid "{0} minute"
msgid_plural "{0} minutes"
msgstr[0] "minuto"
msgstr[1] "{0} minutos"

msgid "January"
msgstr "Janeiro"
...
```

The months are being translated at `input type date` but `minute` at `$this->Time->timeAgoInWords` is not. They are from a different domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, they are in a different domain, the `cake` domain, the months are in that domain too. Take a look at the source, all translatable core messages are in that domain.

I'd suggest that you extract them using the **[I18N shell](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/i18n-shell.html)** (**backup your existing translations first** in case you accidently overwrite them), it won't get simpler than that.

See **[Cookbook Console & Shells > I18N Shell > Generating POT Files](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/i18n-shell.html#generating-pot-files)**

Comment: whats the difference between cake.pot and default.pot?

Comment: One will get you deliciously baked, the other sounds rather boring. @DanielFaria

Comment: Sorry but I'm not understanding. I extracted cake.pot. I have to rename this to defualt.po and move to pt_BR folder? I translated some words in cake.pot and nothing happens.

Comment: @DanielFaria The difference is that one is for the `cake` domain messages, the other for the `default` domain messages. [**As mentioned in the linked docs**](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#language-files), the `.pot` files are templates that you use to create `.po` (or even `.mo`, depends on your tools) files containing the translated messages.

Comment: @DanielFaria And these files must then of course be placed in the corresponding language directories, like `pt_BR`, so `cake.pot` becomes `pt_BR/cake.po` or (`.mo`), and `default.pot` becomes `pt_BR/default.po` (or `.mo`). See **http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/internationalization-and-localization.html#language-files** and **http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gettext** for more information.

Comment: I'm getting this error: `message formatter creation failed: U_ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT_ERROR` from cake.po that comes from cake.pot. I deleted de cake.po content e let only few and I dont get the error, so.. cake.pot is being generated with some error in some part of the file.

Comment: @DanielFaria That's something for a new question where you can add appropriate details, this all has nothing to do with the original question anymore.